# Jackson Spring Check what kind of object came in

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I get a response from the service. It could be as follows:

```
{
    "uid": "f12c394f-5cb7-48b8-bfa5-17d248df4866",
    "data": [
        {
            "vac_status": "1",
            "vaccination_date": "2021-03-16",
            "lastname": "lastname",
            "firstname": "firstname",
            "birth_date": "1993-12-01",
            "gender": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or it could be this.

```
{
    "uid": "f12c394f-5cb7-48b8-bfa5-17d248df4866",
    "data": [
        {
            "cov_status": "2",
            "disease_outcome_date": "2021-05-19",
            "lastname": "lastname",
            "firstname": "firstname",
            "birth_date": "1973-02-01",
            "gender": "1"           
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way I can check what I got? I came up with only to look for matches in the string. (I take the query as a string and look for the words "vac" or "cov") I think this is not the right approach.
Also, I don't know how to properly deserialize if I don't know what came to me.
I don't know what type came to me.

Comment: you can verify whether the response after deserialization is an instance of your required type.

Comment: do you suggest trying to serialize and catch the error? I think this is a bad approach.

Comment: what's the purpose of your response validation? why is even needed at first place? what's the business value of doing it, if needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Jackson `DEDUCTION` mathod of identifying the classes it is deserialising.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class ParseExample {
    static class Status {
        public String gender;
        public String birth_date;
        public String firstname;
        public String lastname;
    }

    static class VacStatus extends Status {

        public String vac_status;
        public String vaccination_date;
    }

    static class DiseaseStatus extends Status{

        public String cov_status;
        public String disease_outcome_date;
    }

    static class Response {
        public String uid;
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
        @JsonSubTypes({
                @JsonSubTypes.Type(VacStatus.class),
                @JsonSubTypes.Type(DiseaseStatus.class)})
        public List<Status> data;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonParser parser = mapper.createParser(ParseExample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test2.json"));
        Response w = parser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Response>() {});
        parser = mapper.createParser(ParseExample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test3.json"));
        Response w2 = parser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Response>() {});
    }
}
```

`test2.json` and `test3.json` are your examples above.

Comment: I like your solution to the problem. Thank you so much for the example with the code!